# How to describe this type of pick up line in French?

Tags: choix-de-mot

> Excusez-moi, je cherche... {pointant du doigt une direction} ...votre numéro de téléphone. (rires) Peut-être que vous pouvez m’indiquer la direction à prendre ?

Je me demande comment s’appelle ce genre de petites plaisanteries qu’on emploie pour briser la glace en abordant une fille dans la rue. Quelle est la différence entre « une phrase de drague » et « une phrase d'approche » ?

En espérant qu’une image vaut mille mots : [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_kAEbsDjlA&feature=youtu.be&t=476).

Comment: Ok, well, I have never heard une phrase de either of those. On drague les filles, oui. Ou les filles draguent les garçons. and in French, I approached someone is not approcher, fyi. Approach is aborder here in French. pick-up ligne cannot be literally translated like that...

Comment: I cannot find a better phrase than "phrase de drague", and I have also found it [here](http://www.buzzly.fr/25-phrases-de-drague-exceptionnellement-ridicules.html) But I see a distinction between *phrase d'approche*, which would be neutral and fairly common, to just break the ice (ex: *salut, on s'est déjà vus, non ?), and a phrase de drague*, which comes possibly after the *phrase d'approche* and would be a not-so-subtle attempt to seduce the "target" with some joking flattery (see the hilarious examples in my link)

Comment: Je trouve pas utile de limiter ce genre de question à aborder une femme uniquement même si les réponses semblent pouvoir s'appliquer indépendamment. Merci !

Comment: Evidemment, vous avez tout à fait raison, les gays aussi se draguent. Mais je vous signale que la question a été posée ainsi et je ne vois pas de mal (calembour proféré intentionellement).

Comment: @Lambie En effet, c'est un état de fait et je me questionne sur l'impact et non sur l'intention etc.. Merci.

Answer (score 6):

Du point de vue de la fille, ça s'appelle "être lourd" (sauf si vous lui plaisez, ce qui n'est que très, très rarement mon cas) ;)
Blague à part, je ne pense pas qu'il y ait une expression sur ce genre de contact.

Update:

Je crois que j'ai trouvé quelque chose qui pourrait correspondre et que les gens disent vraiment dans la vraie vie; ça serait "technique de drague".

Exemple: Un type aborde une fille sur les Champs-Elysées

- Hep, Mademoiselle! C'est quoi ton 06?

Un copain qui accompagne le type réagit à ce que vient de dire son pote:

- Oh, l'autre! La technique de drague moisie!!

Comment: 'Être lourd' en une seule phrase, qui n'est donc pas insistante, ça n'est pas vraiment de la lourdeur...

Answer (score 2):

**phrase d'accroche** est ce qu'on pourrait dire on français.

Référence: comment aborder une femme + phrase d'accroche sous google site:.fr

Ou bien: [comment aborder une femme + phrase d'accroche](http://www.conseil-seduction.fr/aborder-une-femme)

Comment: @Feelew, Except that nobody says that...